# How to make internal links creating plugin to respect ACF?

Tags: posts, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF for displaying a post with different types of contents (some text, it's explanation, it's translation, it's authenticity, it's scholors ect).

Recently I tried a number of internal link creating plugins (like Internal Links Manager, Internal Link Juicer). But none worked. After a little research in the database of my wp, I came to know that, ACF creates metadata, instead of posts. That's why all internal link creating plugins didn't work. since they work only with post and page content. This is so frustrating, I was not aware of this when I installed ACF. Any ideas to make the ACF to convert to post content, (I don't know whether it is a good idea, I am not expert). Or a way to make the internal link creating plugins work with ACF contents?

Comment: Internal links plugins and ACF need an integration. Probably these plugins' authors don't want to do that. [Slim SEO Link Manager](https://wpslimseo.com/products/slim-seo-link-manager/) is adding compatibility to analyze links in custom fields, and promises to work with ACF and Meta Box.